# Is Zangetsu restored after Ichigo gets his powers back?

Tags: bleach

This is really several questions. I do not read the manga so I'm certain this is likely covered there.

First, is Zangetsu fully restored after Ichigo's powers are restored? Does he look different? Both the Shikai and the Bankai appear different in the anime. Did this transformation result in any physical changes to Zangetsu's appearance? Of course, I mean within Ichigo's inner realm.

In the same vein, did Ichigo retain or regain any of his Hollow powers, or were they completely absorbed when he merged with his inner Hollow as revealed in episode 309?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're talking about before the Fullbring arc, Ichigo still has Zangetsu up until the point where he uses Mugetsu to incapacitate Aizen enough for Urahara to seal him. It's at that point that he loses his powers.

****MANGA SPOILERS AHEAD****

If you're talking about the Fullbring arc, that's a completely and wildly different side of the story that has no bearing on the past or the future of the general story. Manga filler.

If you're talking about after the Fullbring arc, then no. Squad Zero restore's Ichigo's powers to a completely different Zanpakutou. It's explained that Zangetsu is a "fake" Zanpakutou that resembles Yhwach that stems from Ichigo's ties to the Quincy bloodline.

Highly suggest you catch up on the manga. You're not that far behind, and it's coming to an end now.

Comment: **UBER RECENT MANGA SPOILER** and we just found out that the Quincy within Ichigo still serves Yhwach, even to the extent of going directly against Ichigo's will

Comment: Interestingly enough, the fullbringer characters do have an impact on the final arc beyond the fact that they were the reason Ichigo even wanted his powers back to begin with, and play a few potentially critical support roles.

Answer (score -4):

Well did you know that  his fullbring fused with his soulreaper powers I mean it's been stated multiple times in the fullbring arc and that was The main purpose for him achieving fullbring so that it can fuse with his soul reaper powers. I know ginjo said that he took all of ichigo fullbring and soul reaper power well that is not true because his was soul reaper was restored by rukia PLUS 30% of his fullbring fused with soul reaper powers.